How to interpret virtual electron neutrino in $e^+e^-\to W^+W^-$?
How can I interpret the virtual particle in this Feynman diagram (time goes from left to right)? Is it an electron neutrino or an electron antineutrino? That is also a general question I have, are vertical lines forward or backward in time, i.e. are they particles or anti-particles?


No. Time axis is vertical and horizontal is $x$ axis. What you have drawn here is electron transforming into positron. Such reaction is impossible normally, and besides your diagram violates charge conservation, because $W^+ + W^-$ does not add to the output charge.

@AgniusVasiliauskas A diagram's validity does not depend on the direction of time, although that can make them represent different physical processes. If time is taken to be vertical, then this diagram represents the scattering process $e^-W\to e^-W$ (although it incorrectly labels one of the charges on the $W$ in that case). But there is nothing wrong with taking time to be left to right, in which case the diagram is labeled fine and properly represents $e^-e^+\to W^-W^+$

Remember that these diagrams are computational tools, and the relevant information is encoded in their topology. It does not matter whether you choose to identify the vertical line with an electron neutrino or antineutrino, because all three cases (unambiguous neutrino, unambiguous antineutrino, and the ambiguous vertical lines) can be smoothly deformed into one another and are topologically equivalent.

This is really a comment to Riley's answer but it got a bit long for a comment.
Feynman diagrams are widely misunderstood outside of the small community that works on quantum field theory. They do not show an actual physical process. They are a graphical representation of an integral that forms one term in an infinite series. Summing all these terms gives us a probability for the interaction between the two particles.
So the vertical line should not be taken to mean there is a (anti) neutrino present because no such particle exists. Instead what happens is the interaction between the electron and positron creates an entangled state that cannot be simply expressed as a sum of an electron and positron so we have to approximate that state as an infinite sum of many other virtual particles.
It doesn't matter whether you take the vertical line to be a neutrino emitted by the electron or an antineutrino emitted by the positron because the integral is the same either way. All you are doing is applying a spurious interpretation to the diagram - "spurious" because the particle is not really there anyway.
